# how to replace class using jquery and part of button id

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a button with dynamic id like this:

btn_732692732692029601_9037087001943716_asif.h@myemail.com

I want to change its class like this:

```
var _idTarget = '#btn_@(Model.RegistryID + "_" + Model.AccountNumber + "_" + Model.Email)';

    $(('input[name^=_idTarget]'), window.parent.document).removeClass('btn_dispute').addClass('btn_dispute_nonempty');
```

but It is not changing class may be due to email address

It was working fine when id was like this

```
  btn_732692732692029601_9037087001943716
```

with this code

```
$(_idTarget,window.parent.document).removeClass('btn_dispute').addClass('btn_dispute_nonempty');
```

but I need to append email address as well.

Please suggest how can i make it working with part of id ( without email)

[Edited]

Here is HTML

```
 <span id="732692732692029601_9037087001943716_asif.h@myemail.com" class="dispute_field">

        <div id="btn_732692732692029601_9037087001943716_asif.h@myemail.com" class="btn btn_dispute"><a>Dispute</a><span></span></div>

</span>
```

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: Can you give a before and after, of what it should start out as, and what it should become? I'm not sure, as written, that I understand.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Please the updated question for html. Thanks

Comment: Is that what you're starting with, or what you want to end up with? I'm sorry; I was asking to see a ***before*** and an ***after***, so that I could see what you're starting with, and what you want to end up with.

Comment: @DavidThomas: I want that when use clicks this div, its css changes : <div id="btn_732692732692029601_9037087001943716_asif.h@myemail.com" class="btn btn_dispute"><a>Dispute</a><span></span></div> from btn_dispute to btn_dispute_nonempty

Comment: @DavidThomas: I am trying to remove the class of parent window from popup using jquery and part of Id of div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use start with selector:
E.g:

```
$('input[id^="btn_732692732692029601"]').removeClass('btn_dispute').addClass('btn_dispute_nonempty');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. One small mistake in question. It is a div not a button.. How to replace input with div ? Please see updated question

Comment: Use `div` in place of `input` in the jQuery selector.

Comment: @DavidThomas: I used this:  $('div[id^="' + _idTarget + '"]', window.parent.document).removeClass('btn_dispute').removeClass('btn_dispute').addClass('btn_dispute_nonempty'); but it didnt work ...

Comment: I tried this and worked: var _idTarget = 'btn_@(Model.RegistryID + "_" + Model.AccountNumber)';    .... removed # before btn_ . Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

can you select class of your div?
$(".btn btn_dispute").removeClass.......
or there is some other element with this class name?